# How to put object inside another object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
var noOfChild=document.getElementById('btnInput').value;

            for(var i=1;i<=noOfChild;i++){
            createJSON();

            function createJSON() {
                alert('working')
                var jsonObj =[];
               var startId=1;
                $("span[id=childNo]").each(function() {
                    var idChildName='childName'+startId;
                    var childName=document.getElementById(idChildName).value;

                    var idDobChild='dobChild'+startId;
                    var dobChild=document.getElementById(idDobChild).value;

                    var idSchoolName='schoolName'+startId;
                    var schoolName=document.getElementById(idSchoolName).value;

                    var idClassSection='classSection'+startId;
                    var classSection=document.getElementById(idClassSection).value;
                    alert(childName);
                    var item = {};
                    item ["child_name"] = childName;
                    item ["child_DOB"] = dobChild;
                    item ["child_class"] = classSection;
                    item ["child_school_name"] = "KV_32";

                   // jsonObj.push("{'"+startId+"':['"+item+"']}");
                    jsonObj.push(item);
                    startId=startId+1;
                });
                var obj={
                    "1":jsonObj
                };
                console.log(obj);
```

I want object like this:

```
{"1":{"child_name": "ytfy", "child_DOB": "1993-06-18", "child_class": "d", "child_school_name": "KV_32"}}
```

But i am getting like this:

```
1:{child_name: "ytfy", child_DOB: "1993-06-18", child_class: "d", child_school_name: "KV_32"}
```

Comment: what problem are you having

Comment: Please add a working snippet.

Comment: sorry i am new to this plz ignore my flaws

Comment: i want to add object inside another object dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation in my opinion is a lot cleaner and nicer to see. The only thing you have to understand is that by calling `objectResult["1"]` you also create a field "1"

```js
var object = {"childName":"foo", "childSurname":"foo"};
var objectResult = {}

objectResult["1"] = object;
console.log(objectResult);
```

Comment: just appending JSON.Stringify(objectResult) works fine now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be simply misreading `console.log()`

If you try this code:

```
var obj = {
  '1': {
    test: 'some data'
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

It outputs `1: {test: "some data"}` to the chrome dev tools console, however it sits below an expandable line that says `Object`, indicating that the line is in fact a child key of an object. So while the console shows this, the actual object does in fact look like:

```
{
  '1': {
    test: 'some data'
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro dont know why its not going to the server

Comment: Now its working.using JSON.Stringify(obj) will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```js
var foo = { "oh" : "yeah" };
var bar = { "no" : "way" };
bar["foo"] = foo;
console.log(bar);
```